# Sound output connector on CD-ROM drive?

Tags: audio, optical-drive, connector

My old CD reader has a volume knob and a minijack socket on the front. On the back it has the regular stuff (IDE interface, Molex power) plus a digital sound connector (DG) and an analog sound connector (RGGL). Is there a specific cable meant for connecting the digital or analog sound output to my motherboard, or do I have to solder one myself?

The CD-ROM drive is a Lite-On LTN-486 and has the ability play CDs and output the sound without communicating with a computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good definition of the CD-ROM cable [here](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/CD-ROM+audio+cable)

> A cable used to send audio CD sound to the computer's sound card. When
>   playing audio CDs, CD-ROM drives output analog sound to both a
>   headphones jack and external connector just like a CD player. This
>   method is still the way audio CDs are played on a computer, but it was
>   the only method available on earlier CD-ROM drives for extracting data
>   from an audio CD. By the mid-1990s, most CD-ROM drives could pass the
>   digital data over the computer's bus (see digital audio extraction).
>
> PCs today use a standard four-pin cable; however, earlier cards and
>   drives used connectors with three to six pins. Finding the right cable
>   was a problem, and the earliest drives had no connector. An advantage
>   of the multimedia upgrade kits that were popular before CD-ROMs were
>   standard issue on a PC was that they included the card, drive and the
>   correct cable. In lieu of this connection, a stereo cable from the
>   headphones jack of the drive to the AUDIO IN of the sound card could
>   always be used.

[image: pc diagram]

Also early drives would have custom interfaces and sound cards would need to support multiple plugs. You could find old SoundBlasters with 2-3 cable headers. The four-pin cable has now become the standard.

[image: cable]

Comment: My motherboard, ASUSTek M4A785TD-V EVO has an integrated sound card, and I can't find any detailed information about the sound card´s specifications, but as far as I know, the motherboard/sound card only have 3 internal audio connectors, 2 of them (1 analog stereo audio output and 1 analog stereo audio input) are already occupied (connected to the front panel), and 3rd one is an S/PDIF audio output. There are 2 audio input sockets on the backpanel. 1 (line-in) is occupied, the last one is for microphones. Can I connect the digital output on the optical drive to the internal S/PDIF?

Comment: Most recent motherboards will not have a header for CD-ROM audio instead relying on DAE. I referring to old sound cards (take a look at the SB 16 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Blaster_16) it has like 4 audio headers at the top of the card.

Answer (score 5):

A cable to connect the analog output to your soundcard was probably supplied with your CD-ROM drive.

Below is a picture of the connector (taken from [Wikicommons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CD-ROM_audio_connectors_2010-10-17.JPG)). You can see also the standardized layout of the 4pin analog output (from left to right)

```
[Right channel] [Ground] [Ground] [Left channel]
```

[image: Audio output of a CR-ROM drive]